# How to quickly contain pluralization failure in API Platform?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Built-in Symfony pluralization sometimes fails and API Platform relying on it builds the resource paths incorrectly (at least not the way I'd like them to be built).

For example: There's an English Dictionary API containing Entries and each Entry resource may have a PartOfSpeech subresource. In fact multiple PartS of Speech.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entry {

    // ...

    /**
     * @var PartOfSpeech[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PartOfSpeech", mappedBy="entry")
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
     public $partsOfSpeech;
}

/**
 * @ApiResource
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
 class PartOfSpeech {

     // ...

     /**
      * @var Entry
      *
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Entry", inversedBy="partsOfSpeech")
      */
      public $entry;
 }
```

So, while I'd like the path to be `parts_of_speech`, API Platform will generate `part_of_speeches` or even `parts_of_speeches` (in case of the subresource) for the obvious reason. I know I can substitute paths operation by operation: `collectionOperations={"get"={"path"="/parts_of_speech/{id}"}}`. But I consider it a bit ugly and inconvenient. Is it possible to enforce a different path in a more elegant way? Preferably in one place per resource. And how to change a path of a subresource?

--

Clarification:

I can almost solve it as:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"path"="/parts_of_speech"},
 *         "post"={"path"="/parts_of_speech"},
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={"path"="/parts_of_speech/{id}"},
 *         "delete"={"path"="/parts_of_speech/{id}"},
 *         "put"={"path"="/parts_of_speech/{id}"},
 *         "patch"={"path"="/parts_of_speech/{id}"},
 *     },
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PartOfSpeech
{
```

It almost does the job but: 1. It's ugly so I ask if there is a shorter, more elegant solution; 2. Even if I write like this, I still don't know how to fix the plural in case of subresource. The following (a guess based on the documentation) doesn't work:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     subresourceOperations={
 *         "part_of_speech_get_subresource"={"path"="/entries/{id}/parts_of_speech"},
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Entry
{
```

and still renders: `/entries/{id}/parts_of_speeches`

Answer (score 0):

To do so you can use the `routePrefix` attribute:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(routePrefix="/parts_of_speech")
 */
class Entity
{
}
```

Comment: It's not what I want. `routePrefix` as the name suggests simply adds a prefix, so I end up having: `/parts_of_speech/part_of_speeches/{id}`, while I'd like to have just `/parts_of_speech/{id}`. I added a bit of clarification to the original question.

Comment: Sorry about that. I don't think that what you try to achieve is possible yet. But it would be a nice addition.
In the meantime you could decorate Doctrine Inflector (the library used for pluralization).

Comment: How could I decorate the Doctrine Inflector to change the default language do Portuguese?